# Material UI and react-hooks-form with yup validation using typescript

Tags: typescript, material-ui, react-hook-form

I'm trying to use React with Material UI and react-hook-form and yup for validation. I am quite new to all parts of this list. I'd like to set up a very basic login form, using the well known Material UI login page and Typescript.

I have a very basic validation at the moment, only a "required" rule is applied. My expectation is when I click submit without filling out the form, I'd like to see the error message under the input its online should turn to red. Just like in the samples shown on the official Material UI page. And here comes the problem... When I click submit without filling out the form, the focus goes on the first field with error and a tooltip appears on the page, but not under the component, it's in more like a "floating bubble", and the outline doesn't turn red. (Even the error message in the floating bubble is something general and not what I set in yup to be displayed.)

I also tried to leave the **yup** out of the project and just use the **rules** attribute, but that lead to the same things.

So here are the components what I use. Sorry if it gets too long, I haven't set up any storage space for this project yet:

```js
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';
import FormControlLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel';
import { FormTextField } from '@tao-ui-shared/form';
import React from 'react';
import { FormProvider } from 'react-hook-form';

import { getLogger } from '../../logging/authenticationLogging';
import { useLoginForm } from '../hooks/useLoginForm';
import { useStyles } from './login.styles';

type LoginFormParams = {
    name?: string;
    classes?: Record<'submit' | 'form', string>
}

export const LoginForm: React.FC<LoginFormParams> = ({
    name
}) => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/unbound-method
    const { register, onSubmit, errors, ...methods } = useLoginForm();

    return (
        <FormProvider register={register} errors={errors} {...methods} >
            <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
                <FormTextField
                    name='email'
                    id='email'
                    variant='outlined'
                    autoComplete='email'
                    label='Email'
                    required
                    autoFocus
                    errors={errors}
                />
                <FormTextField
                    name='password'
                    id='password'
                    variant='outlined'
                    required
                    fullWidth
                    label='Password'
                    type='password'
                    autoComplete='current-password'
                    errors={errors}
                />
                <Button
                    type="submit"
                    fullWidth variant="contained"
                    color="primary"
                >
                        Login
                </Button>
            </form>
        </FormProvider>
    );
}
```

```js
import { FormControl, TextField } from '@material-ui/core';
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { Controller } from 'react-hook-form';


export type FormTextFieldParams = {
    readonly name: string;
    readonly id: string;
    readonly variant: 'standard' | 'filled' | 'outlined' | undefined;
    readonly defaultValue?: string;
    readonly label?: string;
    readonly margin?:  'normal' | 'none' | 'dense' | undefined;
    readonly autoComplete?: string;
    readonly type?: string;
    readonly disabled?: boolean;
    readonly required?: boolean;
    readonly fullWidth?: boolean;
    readonly autoFocus?: boolean;
    readonly minLength?: number;
    readonly maxLength?: number;
    readonly errors?: any;
};

export const FormTextField: React.FC<FormTextFieldParams> = ({
    id,
    name,
    errors,
    variant = 'standard',
    margin = 'normal',
    label = '',
    type = '',
    disabled = false,
    required = false,
    fullWidth = true,
    autoFocus = false,
    autoComplete= ''

}) => {
    const isError = useRef(false);
    const errorMessage = useRef('');

    useEffect(() => {
        Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(errors, name);
        if (errors && Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(errors, name)) {
            isError.current = true;
            // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access,@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment
            errorMessage.current = errors[name].message;
        }
    }, [errors, name]);


    return (
        <FormControl fullWidth={fullWidth}>
            <Controller
                as={TextField}
                id={id}
                name={name}
                variant={variant}
                margin={margin}
                label={label}
                type={type}
                required={required}
                fullWidth={fullWidth}
                autoFocus={autoFocus}
                autoComplete={autoComplete}
                error={isError.current}
                helperText={errorMessage.current}
                disabled={disabled}
            />
        </FormControl>
    );
};
```

```js
import { yupResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers';
import { login } from '@tao-ui-shared/authentication-service'
import { useCallback, useMemo } from 'react';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import * as yup from 'yup';

import { LoginFormData } from '../../types';


export const useLoginForm = () => {
    const validationSchema = useMemo(() => (
        yup.object().shape({
            email: yup.string().required('Username/email is required'),
            password: yup.string().required('Password is required')
        })
    ), []);

    const methods = useForm<LoginFormData>({
        resolver: yupResolver(validationSchema)
    });

    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const onSubmit = useCallback((formValues: LoginFormData) => {
       // Do some logging here and dispatch and action...
    }, []);

    return {
        ...methods,
        onSubmit: methods.handleSubmit(onSubmit)
    }
}
```

Any ideas what am I doing wrong would be very much appreciated!

**UPDATE:**

I played a bit more around this.And probably, somehow I need to get my wrapping form field component to be re-rendered, because it is not happening when the validation fails... Can that be the issue?

Comment: I am not familiar with react-hook-form but I am sure you will need to pass the specific field of the `errors` object to the input fields. Since you are "new to this", you may want to look at [rff-mui](https://github.com/lookfirst/mui-rff) as it integrates deeply and nicely with material-ui and yup

Comment: @japrescott: Thanks for the suggestion. Yes, I had a look on final form, because that's what we use at my workplace. I've just been transformed from backend to full stack, and I still don't know this React world that deep as I expected from myself. But I understand that, and I also saw and read some bottlenecks of final-form. Especially when you have a lot of form fields on the screen e.g. with multi page forms. In this application what I am working on now, if I manage to get through the login page :-), that will be the scenario. Lots of fields on a multi page form.

Comment: finalform allows you to control very nicely when what should rerender with the `subscription` prop.